# How do I make scanf function print whole array

Tags: c, scanf

I wrote a simple code that should read an array and print it, but it doesn't print anything.

What I noticed is that, when I make first for loop go to `n-1` instead of `n` (but second loop still goes to `n`), it actually works. Example:

Input: `1 2 3 4 5 6`
Output:  `1 2 3 4 5 0`

It also works when the second loop goes to `n-1`, so the mistake is in the first loop or `scanf` function.

What can I do to make it print whole array?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 50

int main() {
    int a[MAX_LENGTH];
    int n, i;
    printf("Insert the length of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Insert elements of array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d ", &a[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`

Comment: @xing thank you! It fixed the problem. So scanf functions make spaces beetwen the elements of array without adding space trailing? I thought it works same as printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have a trailing space in the `scanf()` format: `scanf` keeps waiting for more input until you enter something that is not white space, newline being white space.

You should just use `"%d"` as a `scanf()` format.

Furthermore, you should check the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior upon invalid input.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 50

int main() {
    int a[MAX_LENGTH];
    int n, i;

    printf("Insert the length of array: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    if (n > MAX_LENGTH) {
        printf("too many numbers, limiting to %d\n");
        n = MAX_LENGTH;
    }
    printf("Insert elements of array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```